# How do I join these four tables with sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I'm having trouble with my sqlite database. I'm trying to write an query that will generate a total bill for a specific guest (guestID)

GUEST

- GuestID (Primary Key, Type:Integer, Auto increment)
- FName (Type:Text)
- LName (Type:Text)

RESERVATION

- Reservation Number (Primary Key, Type: Integer, Auto increment)
- CheckIN (Type:DateTime)
- CheckOUT (Type:DateTime)
- GuestID (Type:Integer)
- RoomNumber (Type: Integer)

ROOM

- RoomNumber (Primary Key, type: Integer)
- RoomTypeID (type: Integer)

ROOMTYPE

- RoomTypeID (Primary Key, type: Integer)
- Bed (type: Text)
- Price (type: Integer)

I know that I would have to subtract Reservation.checkout from Reservation.checkin to get the number of days then multiply that by the RoomType.price so that would give me a total bill. So how would I write my sql query to give me a total bill for a specific guest (guestid)? I know you can join up to three tables but I don't know how to join these four tables. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways are 1 in the sql or 1 in the application level
1) sql:

```
SELECT g.*, ((strftime('%s',r.CheckOUT) - strftime('%s',r.CheckIN)) * rt.Price/24/60/60) AS total
FROM GUEST g, RESERVATION r, ROOM rm, ROOMTYPE rt
WHERE g.GuestID = r.GuestID AND r.RoomNumber = rm.RoomNumber AND
rm.RoomTypeID = rt.RoomTypeID
```

You can modify to your needs basically the statement is to get the columns in guest table and compute the price he/she needs to pay by subtracting the check out and check in dates in seconds and multiply by the price down to per seconds.

2) app level:
You can probably run 2 sql statements to get the price of the particular room for particular guest. 
Do the computation of price in your whatever language you are using php/ruby/java etc.

Answer (score 0):

Joining those four tables is just a matter of matching up the columns, then everything falls into place:

```
select ...
from guest
join reservation on guest.guestid = reservation.guestid
join room on reservation.roomnumber = room.roomnumber
join roomtype on room.roomtypeid = roomtype.roomtypeid
where guest.guestid = ?
  ...
```

If you don't need the guest's name then you only need to join three tables:

```
select ...
from reservation
join room on reservation.roomnumber = room.roomnumber
join roomtype on room.roomtypeid = roomtype.roomtypeid
where reservation.guestid = ?
  ...
```

Comment: The code seems correct but when I try to run the query I get no results even with select *. All the columns show but no rows.

Comment: @user1025064: What are you using for the `?` placeholder?

Comment: This is my sql code:
select *
from reservation
join room on reservation.roomnumber = room.roomnumber
join roomtype on room.roomtypeid = roomtype.roomtypeid
where GuestID = 1

Comment: @user1025064: You're sure you have all the right data in your tables? Try it without the WHERE clause and see if everything looks right.

Comment: @user1025064: Are you sure the data in your tables is right? Start with `select * from reservation` and add the joins one by one to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Omg I'm an idiot I mistyped some of my data. you were right man. it works now thanks :)

Comment: @user1025064: No worries, we're all idiots sooner or later. You might want to look into [foreign keys](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) to help avoid some data integrity problems.